# Rails log in chrome browser [SOLVED]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, inspect

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css.map"):

actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call' web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in` call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call' web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in` catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call' actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in` call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app' railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in` block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged' activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in` tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged' railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in` call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `block in call' activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:20:in` silence'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/logger.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in broadcast' activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:20:in` silence'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/logger.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast' sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in` call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call' actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in` call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call' rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in` call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call' actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in` call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call' rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in` call'
rack-mini-profiler (2.3.2) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:237:in `call' rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in` call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call' puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in` call'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request' puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in` process_client'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run' puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in` block in spawn_thread'

the above rails log creates only on chrome browser when right click & inspect. If i do not inspect, this will not appears on log file and also if happens only on chrome NOT on any other browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed commented code `/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css.map */` from css file & logs are fine now.